# Rails issue with params hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, hash, parameters

I need to export a previously rendered table from my view to pdf. When I build the array of hashes as follows:

```
__index = 0

@people.each do |p| %>
  @pdfdata[__index] = {                                
    [:name] => p.name.to_s,                         
    [:surname] => p.surname.to_s
    __index += 1
  end
end
```

and send it to the controller in order to export it on a pdf as follows:

```
hidden_field_tag(:pdfdata, @pdfdata)
```

when I get the `params[:pdfdata]` I cannot find a way unless I build a string parser to map the data accordingly... is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying your code a little bit to get

```
 @people.each_with_index do |p,i| %>
   @pdfdata[i] = {                                
    [:name] => p.name.to_s,                         
    [:surname] => p.surname.to_s}
  end
```

and use this gem to create the hidden has field

https://github.com/brianhempel/hash_to_hidden_fields

Comment: Yep, almost did the trick cause hash keys need to have different names, but that can be overcome easily... that's exactly what i was looking for... cheers!!